# Beamer theme with dark background and colour gradient in title

Tags: beamer, themes

[image]

https://blog.jotterpad.app/using-markdown-to-make-beautiful-latex-beamer-presentations/

Hi, I was wondering if anyone knows what beamer template this is or how I can achieve this (color gradient on text + black background) in LaTeX. Thank you!

Comment: This https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Beamer or this https://deic.uab.cat/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with some dark colour theme, e.g. `owl` and then use @Skillmon's great answer https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=5253#a5195 to add some rainbow colours to your title:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{owl}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=darkgray,top=black]

\usepackage{chickenize}
\chickenizesetup{rainbow_step=0.15}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\bfseries\huge\rainbowcolor}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\unrainbowcolor}
\addtobeamertemplate{date}{\vfill}{}

\title{The title of your presentation}
\author{names}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[b]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use the `gradient-text` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{owl}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=darkgray,top=black]

\usepackage{gradient-text}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\bfseries\huge}
\addtobeamertemplate{date}{\vfill}{}

\title[The title of your presentation]{\gradientRGB{The title of your presentation}{255,0,244}{0,238,255}}
\author{names}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[b]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]